# Tagging dimensions and name on image codename one

Tags: codenameone

I have an image( mechanical part of machine ) in my form in which I have to put some measurement like width and height, show arrows for inlet and outlet on image and display name near by each component. How do I proceed for this ?

Note : Width and height come from user as input, so all these dimension depends on user. Basically user will try to design a feasible model based on some calculations. These parameters need to be displayed on image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly you are trying to draw on an image.

For that just create an Image using `Image.createImage(width, height, ARGB_COLOR)` that would generate a "mutable image" which means you can draw on it by invoking `getGraphics()` on the image and using the graphics to draw whatever you want (including other images). You can then save the image to a file using the `ImageIO` class.